# How to add text height in CSS

Tags: css, text

I have one `h1` tag and code looks like this

HTML

```
<h1>Awesome title</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
    line-height:3px
}
```

I want only text to be scaled upwards the width of this text will remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, with transform. For instance, this text is double as tall.

```
.tall {
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1,2); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1,2); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1,2); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1,2); /* Opera */
    transform:scale(1,2); /* W3C */
}
```

It operates like this:

```
transform:scale(width,height);
```

If I want it to be only 1.5 times taller than wide, I could use:

```
transform:scale(1,1.5);
```

Demo:
http://codepen.io/Pachonk/pen/vNVaKr

Comment: thanks it worked also is there is no other way to do that

Comment: It is the only was I know of to physically stretch the text.